# Call methods instead of property with Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval

Example:

I can access `ID` property because there is a property.

But I can't access a method from same class. So `<%# Eval("GetToday") as string %>` don't work.
Creating a property instead of a method with no setter will solve the problem, but exist a better way?

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMyClass">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("ID") as string %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Today">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("**GetToday**") as string %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Code behind:

```
public IList<MyClass> GetMyClass() { return new List<MyClass>(); }
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }

   public string GetToday()
   {
       // other userfulls logic
       return Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
   }

   // workaround
   public string GetTime
   {
       get
       {
          return Date.ToString("HH:mm");
       }

       set
       {
          // nothing
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: No one talked about simply modifying your datasource. You could very well loop on it to add a column/field that has whatever operation you needed done on it already. Just mentioning it because when working with evals thats often been the most efficient solution i've found to problems like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. The ASP.NET `Databinder.Eval` method only supports property expressions, as stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The navigation path from the container object to the **public property** value

There is no alternative for the method call besides properties, which you have found out already.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using the existing DateTime `Date` property you have and apply some text formatting:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMyClass">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("ID") as string %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Today">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Date", "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>    
</Columns>
```

If you must have custom logic, then you can do this in the property instead of using a method, for example:

```
public class MyClass {
   public int ID { get; set; }

   private DateTime _date;
   public DateTime Date
   {
       get
       {
          //do something with the date field here

          // you could add a number of days for example
          _date = _date.AddDays(4);          

           return _date;
       };
       set
       {
           _date = value;
       };
    }   

    public MyClass()
    {
         _date = DateTime.Now();

    }
}
```

Just make sure the private `_date` field is initialised properly, perhaps in a constructor for `MyClass`, i've initialised it to the current date in the example.

Comment: yes, but GetToday()-method is just an example. I need to make other usefull thinks in this method with about 10 lines of code.

Comment: @Xeddon I've updated the answer to give an example of how a property can be used to manipulate the date before it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method, you just have to get the syntax correct:

```
<%= GetToday() %>
```

Comment: That doesn't do late binding as far as I know.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have not experience about this kind of code, but can he add a fake parameter to the method and then call GetToday with some value to have late binding? Something like `<%= GetToday(Eval("Something")) %>` and code behind `public string GetToday(object utterlyUselessParam) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you could create a property with a *get* accessor if it is as simple a method as your example.

As philreed has pointed out if you are just formatting a DateTime then you could use *Eval* on the existing propery:

```
    <%# Eval("Date", "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") %>
```

But if the method is doing something more complex then I would avoid putting complex logic inside a property. Instead you could call a method in the page's code behind that would then call your class's method:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Today">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# GetToday(Container.DataItem) %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
protected string GetToday(object obj)
{
    MyClass mc = obj as MyClass;
    if(mc != null) return mc.GetToday();
    else return "Some default text.";
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but could be used if there is no other alternative.